Can I rescue the bonus bots in Astro’s Playroom before playing Astro Bot?
There are four bonus bots that have been added to Astro’s Playroom that count towards the total of bots rescued in Astro Bot. I understand that to get to them you have to have unlocked the Gatcha machine in the earlier game, but is there also a prerequisite of having got so far in the newer game? Can I rescue them without having played Astro Bot at all?

Having tried it, I can confirm that the bots can be rescued before you’ve ever played Astro Bot.
Slight correction after starting to play Astro Bot: you don’t rescue them in the first game, you simply unlock them so they can then be rescued in the latter game.
